# Flexbox justify-content with padding or margin on one side

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to learn more about flexbox. So, I give myself projects to make solely in flexbox.

Right now I am trying to make a bar with 2 items above it,  One at 50% of the width of the bar and another at 100%  with the resulting figure looking like below.

_____________X___________X  (With the bar continuing under the X)

I thought I could solve this problem with

```
    .parent {
        display: flex;
    }
    .parent .item-child {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
.parent .item-child:first-child {
     padding: 50%;
}
```

There seems to me like there has to be a better way.

Comment: If my answer isn't useful to you I can just delete it. Let me know if you have any questions. I can also revise it based on your feedback. Cheers!

Comment: You're refreshing polite for this site.  I built an answer with flex the day I posted this.  It was a while back, but I can surely post what I did later.